# How to turn off retweet and favorite notifications in Twitter?

Tags: twitter, retweet

Is it possible to turn off retweet and favorite notifications in a Twitter account (e.g. the actual notifications that show up in the Twitter account - not mobile or email notifications).

Every time I log in, I see a thousand retweeted and favorited notifications and I'd love for those to be muted so that only mentions show up.

Answer (score 3):

From the web app:

1. Go to [Settings](https://twitter.com/settings/account) (found by clicking on your profile icon)
2. Click [Web notifications](https://twitter.com/settings/web_notifications) from the sidebar on the left
3. Check or uncheck the notifications you want to see or not see as needed

   In this case it would be to uncheck:

   - My Tweets are retweeted
   - My Tweets are marked as favorites

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. From Twitter's [help page](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170772-enabling-web-notifications): "A web notification is a pop-up notification that appears within your web browser to notify you about DMs, follows, favorites, Tweets and Retweets, from people you follow, when you are logged in to twitter.com." - I did what you said and I'm still getting RT/favorite notifications.

Comment: For what appears/doesn't appear in your Notifications timeline overall, you can't change it

Comment: Previous answer: I don't think that does what you say it does. That'll stop op-up notifications, but the notifications tab will still list all the retweets and favorites. I have the same issue as the OP - I would like to, with 1 or 2 clicks, turn off retweet and favorite notifications in my notifications tab - like my mobile settings has a "mentions only" option.